# iOS Facebook SDK crashes app after revoking app permissions

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with Facebook SDK. In my app I have possibility to remove the app from user's facebook account through Facebook Graph Request:

```
        NSString *graphPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/permissions", [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].userID];
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:graphPath parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"DELETE"]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"Facebook removed");
         } else {
             NSLog(@"Facebook error: %@", error);
         }
     }];
```

Everything works fine, but if I then try to login again using `logInWithReadPermissions` on FBSDKLoginManager, Safari appears, I click "Contiune" to authorize the app and it crashes with error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[3]'
```

When I try to login after launching the app again, everything works fine.

Do you have any clue, what could be the reason for this?

UPDATE:

The exception occurs in one of FBSDKCoreKit files, namely FBSDKTimeSpentData.m, at lines 149-155 we have:

```
NSDictionary *timeSpentData =
  @{
    FBSDKTimeSpentPersistKeySessionSecondsSpent : @(_secondsSpentInCurrentSession),
    FBSDKTimeSpentPersistKeySessionNumInterruptions : @(_numInterruptionsInCurrentSession),
    FBSDKTimeSpentPersistKeyLastSuspendTime : @(now),
    FBSDKTimeSpentPersistKeySessionID : _sessionID,
    };
```

_sessionID is nil
This variable is initialized in

```
- (void)instanceRestore:(BOOL)calledFromActivateApp
```

method, which can be invoked in app by calling

```
[FBSDKAppEvents activateApp]
```

however in the instanceRestore: method there is a condition

```
if (!_isCurrentlyLoaded) {
//
}
```

which is not met, therefore the _sessionID is not set.

Comment: enable the exception breakpoint in xcode and see where it hits when the exception occurs.

Comment: The exception occurs in one of FBSDKCoreKit files, namely FBSDKTimeSpentData.m, at lines 149-155 we have:
NSDictionary *timeSpentData =
  @{
    FBSDKTimeSpentPersistKeySessionSecondsSpent : @(_secondsSpentInCurrentSession),
    FBSDKTimeSpentPersistKeySessionNumInterruptions : @(_numInterruptionsInCurrentSession),
    FBSDKTimeSpentPersistKeyLastSuspendTime : @(now),
    FBSDKTimeSpentPersistKeySessionID : _sessionID,
    };

_sessionID is nil

Comment: exception says, a nill value is being inserted in the dictionary. We can't help unless you post the relevant code.Pls don't post code in commnets. Update your question with all details.

Comment: Sorry. I have updated my post:)

Comment: can you look up and see where the sessionID is initialized and given a value ?

Comment: I have checked it and updated my post above.

Comment: It's not really clear to me whether you are actually calling `FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()` inside your `applicationDidBecomeActive`...are you?

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in Facebook iOS library. Pls, update Facebook SDK library. In FBSDKLoginKit (4.13.1) this bug was fixed.